# How to mark an XQuery expression as deterministic? (In order to persist a computed column from XML values)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a column of type `xml (DOCUMENT <MyDocType>)` for which I have defined a very small schema. Roughly the XML has this simple shape:

```
<root>
    (<a> | <b>)*
</root>
```

So a root with 0 or more child elements of type `a` or `b`. That's it.

I'd like to have a persisted computed column from this data, from the concatenated stringified values of each child of `root`; so I create a UDF to stringify the contents of each document:

```
create function stringify (@doc xml (document MyDocType))
returns varchar(256)
as begin
    return convert(varchar(256), @doc.query('
        for $val in /root/*
            return string($val)'))
end
```

But when using this function as the source of the persisted column, the database complains that the function is not deterministic.

I would say that this function is, to my human intuition, deterministic. But the database appears to not agree with me. I understand that perhaps it is possible for XQuery to do some non-deterministic things, but does that mere possibility taint all XQuery queries with non-determinism?

Is there a way to tell the database that "hey, this function that takes XML and returns a string is deterministic -- let me derive a persisted computed column with it"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create function dbo.xmldata(@thexml xml)
returns nvarchar(max)
with schemabinding, returns null on null input
as
begin
    return @thexml.query('for $val in /root/* return string($val)').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    --return (@thexml.value('return ./root/*/text()', 'nvarchar(max)'))
end
go

create table dbo.testabc
(
    thexml xml,
    thestring as dbo.xmldata(thexml) persisted
)
go

insert into dbo.testabc(thexml)
values('<root><a>aaaaa</a><b>bbbbb</b></root>')
go

select * 
from dbo.testabc
go

drop table dbo.testabc
go
drop function dbo.xmldata;
go
```

Comment: It's the `with schemabinding` that is the magic part. Thanks! I thought this was an XQuery-related problem but it was more of a function definition problem.